# What does "dedicate shrines" mean?

Tags: meaning, metaphors, irony

The sentence:

> They are experiencing 40% inflation, so if they get to 20% inflation (that is still high) they would dedicate shrines.

I searched it a lot but didn't get an answer that makes sense!

Comment: It's an ironic way of saying they'd be happy with inflation cut in half. They'd do somersaults, they'd kiss the ground the Finance Minister walked on, they'd sell their mother to the Taliban.

Comment: @YosefBaskin Whoa dude that's kind of extreme... somersaults?

Comment: It's important to understand that "dedicate" is a verb and "shrines" is a (plural) noun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Religious people may create a shrine for a deity to thank that deity for helping them. In this case, it is a metaphor. Inflation is viewed as a kind of natural disaster that humans have little influence on: if inflation is halved, that is seen as help received from a deity, metaphorically. So dedicating a shrine to a deity is a metaphorical way of saying people would be very, very happy if inflation were halved.

Comment: @Xanne: Heh, oops.